# Select attribute value of parent element in Linq to XML of C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq to XML of C#. I am trying to find out the parent attribute value using Xpath. This Xpath works when I run it against XML but is somehow giving an error in Linq to XML.

The error is:

> Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

and here is the XML:

```
<items>
   <item id="Carrier_ProductBase_Data_3_0_0_0" description="Carrier  ProductBase  Data   (3.0.0.0)" versionDate="2006-12-01">
        <keys>
            <key name="versionID" value="Carrier_ProductBaseData_00_10"/>
                    <key name="family" value="DCTTemplates"/>
                    <key name="lob" value="CarrierAdmin"/>
                    <key name="state" value="Admin"/>
                    <key name="version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
                    <key name="effectiveDateNew" value="2006-12-01"/>
                    <key name="effectiveDateRenewal" value="2006-12-01"/>
                <key name="masterID" value="DuckCreekTech_Master_US_00_20"/>
                    <key name="productCode" value="Data"/>
                </keys>
            </item> </items>


`XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(this.DCTResponseXML);
var s = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//*[@name='productCode'][@value='Data']/../../").Attribute("id").Value;`
```

Comment: Can Someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An xpath can't contain a single slash, and you're going one level to far up. It should be

```
var xpath = @"//*[@name='productCode'][@value='Data']//..//..";
var s = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath). ...
```

Comment: I changed it to var s = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//*[@name='productCode'][@value='Data']//..//..//").Attribute("id").Value; and again same error .